# Design API for taking xpath input from user

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to design API which could handle XPATH input from user.
Currently i have model the XPATH input in following way,

```
public interface ICondition {
    String getConditionString();
}

public class XPathCondition implements ICondition {

    private Class<? extends XPATHFunction> clazz = null;

    private Operator operator = null;

    private String compValue = null;

    private String param = null;

    public void setXPathFunction(Class<? extends XPATHFunction> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void setComparisionType(Operator operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public void setComparisionValue(String value) {
        this.compValue = value;
    }

    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    public String getConditionString() {
        XPATHFunction function = null;
        try {
            function = (XPATHFunction) clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return function.call(param) + operator.getOprValue() + compValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XPathCondition xpathCond = new XPathCondition();
        xpathCond.setXPathFunction(CountFunction.class);
        xpathCond.setParam("/CPRRegistrationInfo/*");
        xpathCond.setComparisionType(Operator.GT);
        xpathCond.setComparisionValue("0");
        System.out.println(xpathCond.getConditionString());
    }
}


public interface XPATHFunction {

    public String call(String param);

}


public class CountFunction implements XPATHFunction {

    public String call(String param) {
        return "count(" + param + ") ";
    }

}
```

There could be other XPATH function which have to implement and interface XPATHFunction and implement it in its way.

API just have create XPATHCondition and set appropriate function and call getConditionString() method to get the final xpath.

Is there any better way, we can model XPATH input?

Please help me to re factor the above design.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. The user enters XPaths? ...and what should the system do with this XPaths..?

Comment: currently we are accepting XPATH as plain string input.I want build xpath using some API.So that it will minimize the chances of error.So user will give the xpath by using our API and final output out API is complete xpath string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I cannot really comment on your class structure or suggest something different. It is a very tough problem.

What I'd suggest is:

- Start with some simple sub-set of the full XPath syntax
- Instead of starting from the design of the API and the classes start designing the user interface: what are you going to show the user? What are his/her possible actions? The class design should then derive from the UI design.
- If possible use a schema for the underlying XML, so that you can present the user with a limited choice of the possible element and attribute name to use in the expression